# By the definition of Riemann Stieltjes integral, show total variation equals the integral of absolute value of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$$V_{a}^{b}(g)=sup_{P}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})|$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}|g'|dx=sup_P\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i*(x_i-x_{i-1})=inf_P\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_i*(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
where $m_i=inf_{x \in[x_{i-1},x_i]}|g'(x)|,M_i=sup_{x \in[x_{i-1},x_i]}|g'(x)|$

Comment: You may need to assume that $g$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: you're right....

Comment: It would be useful to spend some more words. What are the assumptions on $g$? What are you doing, is this homework or is it part of another problem (which one)? Have you tried something? As is, this question is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: It's not a homework, just something I come up. I don't know how to start

Comment: @user251257: I am not sure you can do this. For example, you might have $$g'(x)=\begin{cases} x\sin\frac{1}{x}, & x\in (0, 1]\\ 0& x=0\end{cases}$$ which changes sign infinitely often, so no (finite) partition of $[0,1]$ has the desired property.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yeah. You are right. My bad

Answer (score 2):

In the context of Riemann integration, I remember Rudin giving a proof under the condition that $f'$ is continuously differentiable. It was the last theorem in Chapter 6 of his *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. Unfortunately, I forgot how he did it. Below is a more general discussion in the context of Lebesgue integration.

The sufficient and necessary condition on $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that its total variation
$$
V_a^b(f) = \int_a^b|f'|dm
$$
is $f$ being absolutely continuous. If $f$ is not, the Cantor function can serve as a counterexample. That is, as long as the fundamental theorems of calculus apply, this equality holds.

Suppose $f$ is an absolutely continuous complex function on $[a,b]$. Then $f'$ exists a.e., $f' \in L^1([a,b])$, and
$$
f(x) -f(a) = \int_a^x f'dm
$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$. Define a complex measure $d\mu = f'dm$. It is a consequence of the Radon-Nikodym theorem that $d|\mu| = |f'|dm$, where $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$. By definition of $|\mu|$,
$$
F(x) \leq |\mu|\left([a,x]\right) = \int_a^x|f'|dm
$$
where $F$ is the total variation function of $f$.

Observe that $F$ is itself absolutely continuous, hence $F'$ exists a.e., and
$$
F(x) = \int_a^xF'dm.
$$
Suppose $F'$ and $f'$ both exists at $x$. Note that for any $x\in [a,b]$,
$$
|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq V_x^{x+h}(f)
$$
for any reasonably chosen $h\geq 0$. Combined with the fact that $V_a^b(f)-V_a^x(f) = V_x^b(f)$ for $x\in [a,b]$, we get
$$
|f'(x)| = \lim_{h\to 0}\left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \right| \leq \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = F'(x).
$$
Hence
$$
F(x) \geq \int_a^x|f'|dm,
$$
and the equality is established.

BTW, it is actually worth noting that whenever $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f' \in L^1([a,b])$, $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Nice answer. I have got two questions. 1) Can you elaborate on the "consequence of Radon-Nikodym", equation $F(x)\le \int_a^x |f'(y)|\, dy$? 2) Is it obvious that $F$ is itself absolutely continuous?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro 1) A consequence of the Radon-Nikodym theorem is that for the complex measure defined by $d\lambda = fd\mu$, $d|\lambda| = |f|d\mu$. See Chapter 6 of Rudin's R&C Analysis for related discussions. By definition of total variation of a complex measure and the fact that $f = \int f'dm$, we have the inequality. 2) The fact that $F$ is AC when $f$ is AC is a non-trivial theorem proved in Chapter 7 of the same book. I decided to not include them not because they are trivial, but because of the limit of space and time.

Comment: As a big fan of Rudin, I followed his approach to relate differentiation theories in Lebesgue integrations strongly to the Radon-Nikodym theorem and complex measures. One can definitely study differentiation with more elementary tools, like the way Steins does it in his real analysis book, so Radon-Nikodym theorem is not a must for the first inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also checked Rudin's baby book and especially "the last theorem of Chapter 6" (congratulations, you have an excellent memory). I had never really thought that the concepts of "total variation" and "length of a rectifiable curve" really are the same. Thank you for this insight.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Here's a proof that applies to the case in which $f\colon [a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and that follows the scheme of @QiyuWen 's answer that covers the general case. Let 
$$F(y)=\sup_{\text{partitions of }[a,y]} |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|.$$ 
We claim that 
$$
F(b)=\int_a^b |f'(y)|\, dy.$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, one has that 
$$
|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)| = \left| \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} f'(y)\, dy\right| \le \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |f'(y)|\, dy. $$ 
So for any partition of $[a, b]$ one has that 
$$
\sum_i |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)| \le \sum_i \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |f'(y)|\, dy = \int_a^b |f'(y)|\, dy.$$
Taking the supremum over all partitions, one sees that 
$$F(x)\le \int_a^x |f'(y)|\, dy.$$ 
(This inequality is obtained in QiyuWen's answer by means of the Radon-Nikodym's theorem). In particular, one has that $F(b)\le \int_a^b |f'|\,dy$.

We claim that the opposite inequality also holds. Here we use the uniform continuity of $f'$ and so we are going to diverge from QiyuWen's answer. Namely, let $\epsilon>0$ be fixed and consider a partition $\{x_j\}$ of $[a,b]$ so fine that 
$$\tag{*}
\left|f'(s)-f'(t)\right|\le \epsilon\qquad \forall s, t\in[x_i, x_{i+1}].$$ 
Let $\Delta x= x_{i+1}-x_i$. Then one has that 
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |f'(y)|\, dy &\le |f'(x_i)|\Delta x_i + \epsilon \Delta x_i \\
&=\left| \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f'(x_i)\, dy\right| + \epsilon\Delta x_i \\
&\le \left| \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f'(y)\, dy\right| +2\epsilon\Delta x_i \\
&=\left|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)\right|+2\epsilon\Delta x_i.
\end{split}$$
Summing up one obtains that $\int_a^b |f'(y)|\, dy\le F(b)$, concluding the proof. $\square$

Comment: Nice answer! Now I just feel embarrassed failing to see how the first inequality simply follows...

Comment: @QiyuWen: $F(x)$ is the sup of terms such as $\sum |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|$, and each one of them is dominated by $\sum \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |f'(y)|\, dy=\int_a^x |f'(y)|\, dy$. (Did I understand your question correctly?) I think that this approach yields the inequality also in the general case of an absolutely continuous $f$, but is probably not so trivial. That's maybe why Rudin chose to use Radon-Nikodym's instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood your argument, was just saying that I should have come up with the more elementary but equally general method myself. The Radon-Nikodym theorem provides a quick proof that AC leads to fundamental theorem of calculus, as opposed to classifying all kinds of behaviours of an AC function, which is cumbersome and uninteresting to me. And it's natural to view integrable functions and complex measures as unified.